# How to convert a $expr mongo shell query to mongoTemplate?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongotemplate

Following is my collection:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "favorite": {
      "color": "red",
      "foods": {
        "fruits": "banana",
        "fastfood": [
          "burger",
          "sandwich"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "favorite": {
      "color": "green",
      "foods": {
        "noodles": "ramen",
        "fastfood": [
          "fries",
          "burger",
          "corn dog"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "favorite": {
      "color": "red",
      "foods": {
        "soup": "cream soup"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I need to check fastfood item is Identical or not. To achieve this, I have the mongo shell query already.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      [
        "burger",
        "sandwich"
      ],
      "$favorite.foods.fastfood"
    ]
  }
})
```

But, I need this in **mongoTemplate** as I am using Spring Boot Application. I can not do it so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think the translation to `MongoTemplate` could be this one where you say to mongo "give me the elements where `favorite.foods.fastfood` is `["burger", "sandwich"]`.

```java
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("favorite.foods.fastfood").is(List.of("burger", "sandwich")));
return mongoTemplate.find(query, YourDesiredDocument.class);
```

But it will return data if the array is exactly the same including the elements order.

So for example array `["burger","sandwich"]` [will work fine](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k-9wpkxdVCN).
But `["sandwich","burger"]` [will not return any data](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fncX8IgpD24).

Maybe you don't need this but it can help, you can also try [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1XEthDaFKbM) where order is noy checked, so all arrays with these elements will be returned.

Using `MongoTemplate` it can be something like this (not tested):

```java
Query query = new Query(new Criteria().andOperator(
            Criteria.where("favorite.foods.fastfood").all("burger", "sandwich"),
            Criteria.where("favorite.foods.fastfood").size(2)
        ));
return mongoTemplate.find(query, YourDesiredDocument.class);
```